# Spring boot how to test controller response

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, assert, spring-boot-test

I try to test the response of the controller. I wrote simple test

```
String expectedResponse = "{price:type correct price}";

final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:"+randomServerPort+"/api/products/1";
URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);

ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
productModel.setPrice(-1.0);
productModel.setName("Logitech G-403");

HttpEntity<ProductModel> request = new HttpEntity<>(productModel);
ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);

assertEquals(400, result.getStatusCodeValue());
assertEquals(expectedResponse,result.getBody());
```

Test result:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :{price:type correct price}
Actual   :{"price":"type correct price"}
```

My question is how to test if the response returned by the controller is correct? I tried to do it on the map and on the String (shown above) but neither of them works properly

Answer (score 1):

You should use Spring's `MockMvc` for making requests against your web layer. You can refer to this [getting started guide by Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).